# Microsoft Graph | How to allow an app to access only certain users or mailboxes instead of ALL?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We are using an app as method of authentication in order to connect to user mailboxes and retrieve email for analyses purposes.

Everything is working, however, our "app" has to much access and I need to know how to limit it to only allow access to certain users / groups?

Current setup:
App was created by an admin (who is also an owner of the app)
Mail Read permissions are set
[image]

But this permission gives our "app" access to all of the mail boxes.

Question:

**How can this app be limited to have access only to certain mail boxes / users / groups?**

Comment: The answer FTR is no, you cannot limit the mailboxes it as access to.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: thank you for clarification. I wonder if there is another authentication mechanism (not using an app) that might have capabilities to have access limitations?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - isn't it now possible to limit an app to only certain mailboxes? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: That was added recently. It wasn't available back when you originally asked this question.